# Scanning long string and adding extra character in Python

Tags: python, arrays, string

I need to scan a long string to determine numbers and put commas after every number. But digits are not the same and randomly changes.

little sample = `14 194 180 119 195 213 175 220 133 24  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   72  288 319 345 275 145 5`

Here is what I tried so far

```
for i in range(len(my_values)):
if my_values[i] in (range(999)):
    my_values[i] = ","
```

But It gave me strange output

> ['0', '\t', '0', '\t', '0', '\t', '0', '\t', '0', '\t', '1', '2', '5', '\t', '2', '7', '1', '\t', '3', '0', '8', '\t',

Note: isdigit or isNumeric functions are valid for one character. They did not work.
What should I change to add commas on string after randomly changes number?

Comment: `",".join(my_values.split())`

Comment: Is the string composed of numbers separated by spaces?

Comment: @DarrylG Yes. It is read from text file But I don't think reading part causes the challenge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all numbers as:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = re.findall('-?\d+\.?\d*', sample)
>>> a
['14', '194', '180', '119', '195', '213', '175', '220', '133', '24', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '72', '288', '319', '345', '275', '145', '5']
```

and then join as:

```
>>> ", ".join(a)
'14, 194, 180, 119, 195, 213, 175, 220, 133, 24, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 72, 288, 319, 345, 275, 145, 5'
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks!. It did work. Can you explain what '\d+' part is doing?

Comment: Its a regular expression to extract number with 1 or more digits. Do accept the answer if its working for you.

Comment: I will :). There is a time duration. Thanks again

Comment: This works assuming there are no negative nor fractional numbers in the string.

Comment: What if negative numbers also exist?  Should we scan again?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply try to break the string based on spaces/tab and combine the obtained elements using a comma:

```
new_str = ",".join(my_values.split(' '))    #or '\t' if they are separated by a tab
```

Comment: Best use just `.split()`, without an argument.

Comment: @Błotosmętek Agreed!